# Get indexes of same object in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have `NSMutableArray` with objects like this : **"0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0"**

And i need to get indexes of all objects with value "1"

I'm trying to get it with following code:

```
for (NSString *substr in activeItems){
            if ([substr isEqualToString:@"1"]){
                NSLog(@"%u",[activeItems indexOfObject:substr]);   
            }
    }
```

But as it says in documentation method `indexOfObject:` " returns - The lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to anObject."

**Question**: How i can get all indexes of array with value of "1" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this method of `NSArray`:

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

([documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW24))

```
NSIndexSet *set = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isEqualToString:@"1"];
}];
```

And this is how you can get the indexes as the elements of an array (represented by `NSNumber` objects):

```
NSIndexSet *set = // obtain the index set as above

NSUInteger size = set.count;

NSUInteger *buf = malloc(sizeof(*buf) * size);
[set getIndexes:buf maxCount:size inIndexRange:NULL];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

NSUInteger i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:buf[i]]];
}

free(buf);
```

and then `array` will contain all the indexes of the matching objects wrapped in `NSNumber`s.

Comment: Thanks, but how i can put all data from NSIndexSet to NSMutableArray?

Comment: @anonymous For example, you can recursively walk it and make NSNumbers out of the indexes. Please make some effort researching the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the **indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:** method of NSArray, providing a block as argument to check your objects.

It will return a NSIndexSet.

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

And then to access indexes from the `NSIndexSet`,

```
[indexset enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      //idx is what you want!
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest%3a)):

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [activeItems indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isEqualToString:@"1"];
}];
```

Once you have the indexes, you can get the subset of the original array, containing just the objects you are interested in, using `[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectsAtIndexes%3a)):

```
NSArray *subset = [activeItems objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Comment: Why that for loop with the call to `isEqualToString:`?

Comment: @anonymous Please see my edit for a way to get the subset of objects from the original array.